# Conditional probability on dice rolling

Tags: conditional-probability, dice

Let's roll four dice. What is the probability that there is no "4" on any of the dice conditional on each dice having different values.

My answer is the following:

$$\frac{5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2}{6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3}$$

The denominator being all events with different values; The numerator being all events with different values but "4".

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I think it's pretty much correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning seems fine.

You can also reason alternatively as follows:

Notice that since you are given that the four dice are all different, then your four rolls will include exactly $4$ of the $6$ values from $1$ through $6$. So any given value has a $\frac46$ chance of occuring.